# how to: radio button changing opacity of image

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to light an image up using javascript when a radiobutton is selected.

I tried it with a forEach function, but with the code given, all the images just change to opacity 1;

Also, when i refresh my page, the radiobutton is still selected.

```js
let img = document.querySelectorAll('.poll_img');
    let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');

    radio.forEach(radioButton => {
        if (radioButton.checked = true){
            img.forEach(image => {
                image.style.opacity = 1;
            })
        }
    })
```

```html
<form class="poll_form" action="">
  <div class="poll_bar">
    <img class="poll_img poll_img1" src="assets/images/poll_bar-icon.svg" alt="">
    <label class="radio_title" for="radio1">Atlantic Forest, South America
    </label><input class="radio_button" type="radio" name="group1" id="radio1">
    <div class="check"></div>
  </div>

  <div class="poll_bar">
    <img class="poll_img  poll_img2" src="assets/images/poll_bar-icon.svg" alt="">

    <label class="radio_title" for="radio2">Borneo Island, Southeast Asia
    </label><input class="radio_button" type="radio" name="group1" id="radio2">
    <div class="check"></div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of iterating over the buttons whenever the JS runs the first time and setting the style then, you will want to set up event listeners to run a function whenever the radio buttons are selected.

I suspect you will also not want to iterate over all the images, but rather change the opacity for the image that goes with the particular radio button.

```
radio.forEach(r => {
  r.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let relatedImg = r.parentNode.querySelector("img");
    relatedImg.style.opacity = 1;
  }
})
```

If you want only the currently selected image to have the full opacity, you'd need to also run a function within the event that sets opacity back to 0 or whatever for all the other images.

Edit: a simple way to do that could be something like this.

```
radio.forEach(r => {
  r.addEventListener("click", () => {
    let relatedImg = r.parentNode.querySelector("img");
    updateImages(relatedImg);
  }
})

function updateImages(changedImg) {
  img.forEach(image => {
    if (image === changedImg) {
      image.style.opacity = 1;
    } else {
      image.style.opacity = 0;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's close to working fully now, when i select a radiobutton the img changes opacity, but as you insinuated i only want the related img to change. The problem is that once i select a radiobutton, it doesn't change back.

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible solution to change the other images as well. You may need to convert the `img` variable to an actual array, rather than a NodeList, for it to work in all browsers.

Answer (score 0):

In JS `=` is for assign, not comparing. You need to use `==`.

The condition (line 5 in your JS code) should be

`if (radioButton.checked == true) {...`

or just

`if (radioButton.checked)`

Comment: If i select a radio button nothing happens, no changing, no errors

Answer (score 0):

```
        let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');


    radio.forEach(r => {
        r.addEventListener("click", changeOpacity)
    });

}

changeOpacity = r => {
    const radio = r.currentTarget;
    let relatedImg = radio.parentNode.querySelector('img');
    relatedImg.style.opacity = 1;

    if(radio.checked == false){
        relatedImg.style.opacity = 0.3;
    }
}
```

The opacity changing works, but once selected, the image doesn't lower

Answer (score 0):

You must assign an event to your radio input, You can do that using two methods

**1. First**

to include your js code in a function and call this function on your HTML
HTML:

```
<form class="poll_form" action="">
    <div class="poll_bar">
      <img class="poll_img poll_img1" src="picture.png" alt="">
      <label class="radio_title" for="radio1">Atlantic Forest, South America
      </label><input onchange="lightUpPic()" class="radio_button" type="radio" name="group1" id="radio1">
      <div class="check"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="poll_bar">
      <img class="poll_img  poll_img2" src="picture.png" alt="">

      <label class="radio_title" for="radio2">Borneo Island, Southeast Asia
      </label><input onchange="lightUpPic()" class="radio_button" type="radio" name="group1" id="radio2">
      <div class="check"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

JS:

```
function lightUpPic(){
let img = document.querySelectorAll('.poll_img');
    let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');
    radio.forEach(radioButton => {
        if (radioButton.checked == true){
            img.forEach(image => {
                image.style.opacity = 1;
            })
        }
    })
}
```

**2. Second**

To add Event Listener (addEventListener) to your radio inputs to execute the desired JS on click

Comment: The first method will be appropriate in case you need to light up the pictures in case of  selecting a specific radio button.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit confused to what you're explaining. The code you linked me is the code i already used in JS, but that's not working. Also I don't want to use scripts in html, I want to keep them external. I had some progress in my last answer, (above your answer) but the opacity is not changing back to 0.3 when another button is not selected anymore.

Comment: Your answer would be so much better with the code copied in text, and available to copy again...

Comment: @ArthurRobaeys Kindly clarify what you wanna do exactly.
 you have two radio button. each one controls the opacity of a specific picture. the initial condition for both pictures is opacity = 0.3. on click on a radio you need its assigned picture opacity = 1 and on click on the other one the first picture back to opacity = 0.3. is that right ?

Answer (score 0):

i finally figured it out, thanks to Miles Grover.

```
{
const init = () => {

    let radiobutton = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');


    radiobutton.forEach(r => {
        r.addEventListener("change", changeOpacity);
    });


}

changeOpacity = r => {
    const radio = r.currentTarget;
    let relatedImg = radio.parentNode.querySelector('img');
    relatedImg.style.opacity = 1;

    unsetOpacity();
}

const unsetOpacity = () => {
    let radiobutton = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');
    radiobutton.forEach(r => {
        if(r.checked == false){
            let relatedImg = r.parentNode.querySelector('img');
            relatedImg.style.opacity = 0.1;
        }
    })
}

init();
```

}

Answer (score 0):

**Try this : it achieves the following**

- at page loading all picture have opacity = 0.3
- On selecting radio button 1. picture 1 opacity =  1, rest = 0.3
- On Selecting radio button 2, pic 2 opacity = 1, rest = 0.3 .. etc

**HTML:**

```
<form class="poll_form" action="">
    <div class="poll_bar">
      <img class="poll_img  poll_img1" src="picture.png" alt="">
      <label class="radio_title" for="radio1">Atlantic Forest, South America
      </label><input onchange="lightUpPic(event)" class="radio_button" type="radio" name="group1" id="radio1">
      <div class="check"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="poll_bar">
      <img class="poll_img  poll_img2" src="picture.png" alt="">

      <label class="radio_title" for="radio2">Borneo Island, Southeast Asia
      </label><input onchange="lightUpPic(event)" class="radio_button" type="radio" name="group1" id="radio2">
      <div class="check"></div>
    </div>
  </form>
```

**JS:**

```
    let allImages = document.querySelectorAll('.poll_img');
allImages.forEach(i=> i.style.opacity=0.3);

function lightUpPic(evt){
    let imageNumber = evt.target.id.replace( /^\D+/g, '');
    let imgAssigned = document.querySelectorAll('.poll_img' + imageNumber);

    let radio = document.querySelectorAll('.radio_button');
    radio.forEach(radioButton => {
        if (radioButton.checked == true){
            allImages.forEach(image => {
                image.style.opacity = 0.3;
            })
            imgAssigned[0].style.opacity=1;

        }
    })
}
```